# check if a number combination is found in a list of combinations

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, conditional-statements, combinations

I am creating a program in Python simulating multiplication flash cards. I've gotten pretty far but I can't figure out how to not repeat combinations of numbers. How do I check if a pair of numbers has already been presented?

```
from __future__ import division
from itertools import combinations
import random
amountCorrect = 0
amountMissed = 0
comb = combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 2)

print("Type 0 at any time to exit and see your score.")
while True:
  firstNumber = random.randint(1,12)
  secondNumber = random.randint(1,12)
  ans = int(input("What is " + str(firstNumber) + " x " + str(secondNumber) + ": "))
  if ans == 0:
    break
  elif ans == firstNumber * secondNumber:
    amountCorrect += 1
  else:
    amountMissed += 1

totalProblems = amountCorrect + amountMissed
percentCorrect = amountCorrect/totalProblems

if .9 < percentCorrect <= 1:
  print("Great job, you are doing awesome!")
elif .7 <= percentCorrect <= .89:
  print("You are doing well,keep it up.")
elif .5 <= percentCorrect <= .69:
  print("You are half way to becoming a master.")
else:
  print("Keeping practicing, you will be a master one day.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, use a set to store the pairs of numbers you have already used. Here is some code. You never use `combinations` in your code so I removed it.

```
from __future__ import division
import random
amountCorrect = 0
amountMissed = 0
highestNumber = 12

print("Type 0 at any time to exit and see your score.")
used = set()
while True:
  if len(used) == highestNumber ** 2:
      break
  while True:
    firstNumber = random.randint(1,highestNumber)
    secondNumber = random.randint(1,highestNumber)
    pair = (firstNumber, secondNumber)
    if pair not in used:
      used.add(pair)
      break
  ans = int(input("What is " + str(firstNumber) + " x " + str(secondNumber) + ": "))
  if ans == 0:
    break
  elif ans == firstNumber * secondNumber:
    amountCorrect += 1
  else:
    amountMissed += 1

totalProblems = amountCorrect + amountMissed
percentCorrect = amountCorrect/totalProblems

if .9 < percentCorrect <= 1:
  print("Great job, you are doing awesome!")
elif .7 <= percentCorrect <= .89:
  print("You are doing well,keep it up.")
elif .5 <= percentCorrect <= .69:
  print("You are half way to becoming a master.")
else:
  print("Keeping practicing, you will be a master one day.")
```

I just created an empty set called `used`, and added a new inner loop. That loop test if the pair of numbers has already been used. If so, it just loops again and tries a new pair of numbers. I also added a variable to store the highest possible number, and test of the `used` set is full. I end the quiz if it is full. Without this, when all possibilities are tried the program will go into an infinite loop.

Note that this code will allow both `1,2` and `2,1`. If you want to allow only one of those, add both `(firstNumber, secondNumber)` and `(secondNumber, firstNumber)` to the `used` set.

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for the reply. I should have clarified. I need to test all combinations. The code you provided stops as soon as a pair matches a combination in the set ( ) even if all combinations have not yet been tested.

Comment: @cdelaura: My code does not *stop* when it matches a previously-used combination--it loops again and chooses another random combination. I tested my code with smaller values of `highestNumber` and it seems to work just as I want it to. If all combinations have been tried, my code then ends the quiz as if the user had typed an answer of `0`. If you do not want this, what do you want to happen?